# asdf-vm won't properly install Terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, asdf, asdf-vm

I'm want to use asdf-vm with Terraform and Terragrunt in my WSL2.
I was able to install Terraform and it seems to work, but I can't get Terragrunt running.
I can install a version, but as soon as I try to run a command I get an error:

```
$ terragrunt --version
No terragrunt executable found for terragrunt 0.28.24
```

I found a few people having issues with $PATH, causing similiar problems, but this doesn't seem to be the problem here:

```
$ which terragrunt
/home/lukas/.asdf/shims/terragrunt
$ echo $PATH
/home/lukas/.asdf/shims:...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:
asdf won't work if you use it inside a mounted directory.